# Why does a variable potential divider have the ability to reduce current through a component to zero

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

For example, the diagram in my text book: 
[image: Variable potential divider] 
 shows a filament lamp, in series with a uniform resistive wire, which can have its voltage and current varied by moving the sliding contact, e.g., a rotatable wheel. However, why is a potential divider able to reduce the current through the filament lamp to zero, but a variable resistor in series with the filament lamp cannot reduce current to zero?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as well as possible the short vertical length of wire below the variable resistor should be absent. In practice it makes no effective difference, but people start asking about it's resistance and affect on the result. SO assume the bottom wire is attached TO the bottom of the resistive element. Thusly -

[image]

The unloaded potentiometer voltage varies with it's position on the resistive element.
At the top $V_\text{out}$ will be $V_\text{in}$.
At the bottom $V_\text{out}$ will be 0.

When loaded with a bulb $V_\text{out} \leq$ the unloaded value.
At the bottom $V_\text{out} = 0$,
so $I = V/R_\text{load} = 0/R_\text{load} = 0$,
so no light.

When the bulb is connected to the battery in series with a variable resistor the resistance will be (Rresistor + Rbulb) and the current will be
Ibulb  = Vin / (Rresistor + Rbulb).
For Ibulb to be zero the combined resistance must be infinite.
As the combined bulb and variable resistance is always finite the current will always be non zero. eg for a 10 Megohm combined resistance and 10 volt supply the current will be 10V/10,000,000 Ohm = 1 uA.

Practical issues:

For a tungsten filament incandescent bulb Rbulb drops as Ibulb drops.

If an LED is used then the effective resistance of the LED is extremely high at very low currents.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know that resistance is proportional to length, and hence the shorter the wire the less the resistance. However even at an extremely small length (I.e., at the top) surely there would still be some resistance, hence still a small voltage/current.

Comment: @John If thisis homework/assignment you should say so. If not also please advise. | You are reading things I did not say into what I wrote. Assuming you are still talking about the potejntial dividier (and you should make clear what you are talking about) - I said - "voltage varies with its position on the resistive element." ie Vout_unloaded = Vin x (% distance freom bottom). When distance = 50% V = Vin x 50%. When distance = 0% Vout = Vin x 0%. Yes? Ony once happy that that is so, move on to next case.

Comment: This is not homework, it's just understanding a topic. I know you did not state that R is proportional to L, but this is why the resistance and voltage varies - correct? I understand that the voltage varies with the movement of the slider, as this affects the resistance. When the slider is at the bottom, we're saying that the voltage out of the bulb = 0, hence the current = 0. However for the voltage to be 0, surely this assumes that the potential divider (at the bottom) has infinite resistance, which is not possible. Must there not be a very small amount of voltage across the bulb?

Comment: @John You need to look at the divider in the potentiometer version and see how it functions. Assume that the resistance changes linearly across the length. The top is AT Vin exactly - essentially by definition. The bottom is  AT Ground = 0 Volts exactly - essentially by definition. Look at your diagram - The bottom of the bulb, the pot and the battery are AT exactly the same potential = 0V. All the same. If you connected bulb top top bulb bottom what would happen?If you connected bulb top top battery bottom what would happen? Both are AT 0V. Yes? Now ....

Comment: @John .... If you connected bulb top to pot bottom what would happen? It too is at 0 Volts, yes? Bottom = 0 V regardless of what is connected to it (assuming ideal wire etc). The Pot is designed to divide Vin across its length. With no load at 100% (top) Vout = Vin x 100%. At 50% setting (half) Vout = 50% x Vin. At 10% setting Vout = 10% Vin. SO at 0% setting (bottom) Vout = 0% x Vin.  | Think of pot as being like a waterfall falling from a 100 metre edge. Head of water (ignoring flow energy which is another issue) is proportional to distance from bottom. At middle head is 50m of water. ....

Comment: At bottom there is NO head - the water at the bottom will not by itself flow away without extra fall being provided (of flow energy).

Comment: Whether the question is homework is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielSank  In SE EE and, aiui, in all SE, homework questions are not treated in the same manner as others either by the system or, in most cases,  by individuals  who answer. If people know it is a homework question and wish to help, then  the manner in which they do so may (and often does) differ from when it is a "real world" technical question. I can BEST help a person seeking assistance with homework by aqssisting them to think, to better understand things they are unclear on and bu steering them in the right direction so they learn.  Spoon feeding is usually sub-optimal in such cases.

Comment: @John Yes, you are right that practically even a small length of wire has resistance thus the voltage across the lamp in practice cannot be zero. But it is very close to zero and thus considered so. ( It would be zero if the wire was a superconductor- that is an ideal wire with zero resistance)

Comment: @TausifHossain Your comment about wire resistance is correct **BUT** that is not what John was talking about. His comment was re divider resistance being large and reflected his misunderstanding of how a divider works. I have updated my answer and hopefully it will help somewhat to clarify the difference in the two cases.